# hibernate how manytone query return all the values from primary table

Tags: hibernate

I have following 2 classes Employee and Phonenumber with onetomany relationship between employee and phonenumber:
Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employee_id")
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
private Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>(0);

public Set<PhoneNumber> getPhonenumbers() {
return phonenumbers; 
}

public void setPhoneNumbers(Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers) {
this.phonenumbers = phonenumbers; 
}
```

Phone number
    @Entity
    @Table(name="phone_number")
    public class PhoneNumber {

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employeeid;

public Employee getEmployeeid() {
return this.employeeid;
}

public void setEmployeeid(Employee employeeid) {
this.employeeid = employeeid;
}

1) employee
columns:
id
name

2) phone_number
columns:
employee_id(FK)
phone_number_type
phone_number
```

I want to execute a query where I can search for a phone number that employee might have and return all the data. Basically If I search for a phonenumber I want to get the employee and also all the phonenumbers for the employee. If for some reason 2 employees share a phone I want to return all the information for both the employees. I used  following sample query but it doesnt return all the phonenumbers that the employess has.

```
String key = new String("phone_number_type");
String value = new String("phone_number");

Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq(key, search.getPhonenNumbertype().toString()))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq(value, search.getPhoneNumber()));

return (List<Employee>) criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Do I need to create custom HQL to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by criteria as well as in HQl. Following hql will return your expected result.
select employeeId.id,employeeId.name from PhoneNumber where number=mobile.